# How to copy objects with updates in nested objects in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React component that has some form fields in it:

```js
<TextField
  label="Description"
  id="description"
  value={company.companyDescription}
  onChange={updateFormField("companyDescription")}
></TextField>
```

and a function that updates my company state whenever the values change:

```js
const updateFormField = (property: string) => (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setCompany(prev => ({ ...prev, [property]: event.target.value }))
}
```

This means that whenever a form field changes I'd like to create a new copy (hence the spread operator) of the old object.

My problem is that company has nested properties in it, like `company.location.address`:

```json
{
  name: "some company",
  location: {
    address: "some street"
  }
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way to refactor the above function to update the nested properties? For example something like:

```js
const updateFormField = (property: string[]) => (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setCompany(prev => ({ ...prev, [...property]: event.target.value }))
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to merge the old/new objects for your `company[property]`?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm creating a new object every time (this is how React works). I'd like to overwrite specific properties, like `company.name` or `company.location.address`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a particularly neat solution to this, however it should be possible to loop through selecting/adding the new path:

```js
const updateFormField = (property: string[]) => (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setCompany(prev => {
    // Take a copy of the state
    const newObj = { ...prev }
    // Set up a refernce to that object
    let selected = newObj
    // Loop through each property string in the array
    for (let i = 0; i < property.length; i++) {
        // If we're at the end of the properties, set the value
        if (i === property.length - 1) {
            selected[property[i]] = event.target.value
        } else {
            // If the property doesn't exist, or is a value we can't add a new property to, set it to a new object
            if (typeof selected[property[i]] !== 'object') {
                selected[property[i]] = {}
            } 
            // Update our refernce to the currently selected property and repeat
            selected = selected[property[i]]
        }
    }
    // Return the object with each nested property added
    return newObj
  )}
}
```

Plain JS working example of the same method:

```js
const test = (prev, property, value) => {
  const newObj = { ...prev
  }
  let selected = newObj
  for (let i = 0; i < property.length; i++) {
    if (i === property.length - 1) {
      selected[property[i]] = value
    } else {
      if (typeof selected[property[i]] !== 'object') {
        selected[property[i]] = {}
      }
      selected = selected[property[i]]
    }
  }
  return newObj
}

console.log(test(
  {"a": "1"},
  ["b", "c", "d"],
  100
))

console.log(test(
  {"a": "1"}, 
  ["a", "b"], 
  100
))

console.log(test(
  {"a": {"b": {"c": 1}}},
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  100
))
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I suspected that this was the case. :(

Comment: No problem, hopefully someone else can answer with an operator/pattern I don't know about, but unfortunately I've not come across one.

Answer (score 1):

Object.assign() and dynamically finding the inner reference should do it. I'm assuming the input type of string[] above indicates the nested path is an array like ['company', 'location', 'address']:

```
const updateFormField = (property: string[]) => (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setCompany(prev => {
    const copy = Object.assign({}, prev);
    let ref = copy;
    for (let i = 0; i < property.length - 1; i++) {
      ref = ref[property[i]];
    }
    ref[property[property.length - 1]] = event.target.value
    return copy;
  });
}
```